# Create new column based on other columns and date conditioning

Tags: r

I wanna create a new column based on the data in column 2 - 4, conditioning if the date column  is before or after the previous row. My data looks as follows:

```
date        city1  city2   city3    
2022-01-25  Paris  London  Berlin  
2022-01-28  Paris  London  Berlin  
2022-02-04  Paris  London  Berlin  
2022-01-26  Paris  London  Berlin  
2022-02-08  Paris  London  Berlin  
2022-02-02  Paris  London  Berlin  
2022-02-04  Paris  London  Berlin  
2022-02-06  Paris  London  Berlin
```

The expected output looks as follow:

```
date        city1  city2   city3   NewColumn 
2022-01-25  Paris  London  Berlin  Paris
2022-01-28  Paris  London  Berlin  Paris
2022-02-04  Paris  London  Berlin  Paris
2022-01-26  Paris  London  Berlin  London
2022-02-08  Paris  London  Berlin  London
2022-02-02  Paris  London  Berlin  Berlin
2022-02-04  Paris  London  Berlin  Berlin
2022-02-06  Paris  London  Berlin  Berlin
```

This is what I have tried:

```
for (i in 2:4){
new_data <- data %>% mutate(NewColumn = ifelse(
    as.Date(date) > lag(as.Date(date)), data[,i], data[,i+1]))}
```

But this only generates:

```
date        city1  city2   city3   NewColumn 
2022-01-25  Paris  London  Berlin  <NA>
2022-01-28  Paris  London  Berlin  Berlin
2022-02-04  Paris  London  Berlin  Berlin
2022-01-26  Paris  London  Berlin  London
2022-02-08  Paris  London  Berlin  London
2022-02-02  Paris  London  Berlin  Berlin
2022-02-04  Paris  London  Berlin  Berlin
2022-02-06  Paris  London  Berlin  Berlin
```

How can I solve this? Any advice?

Comment: `tidyr::fill(NewColumn, .direction = "up")` would be a quick fix.

Comment: Could you illustrate this further, given my sample code. I don¨t get it to work.

Comment: Hi @KalleBlomkvist, I rolled back your edit removing your question text — even though your question has been answered, leaving it here will help others with similar questions in the future. If you really want to remove it, you could delete it (rather than editing it to remove all the content), but I would encourage you to leave it up.

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr. Creating a custom group, we can use it to mutate the new values into the column

```
library(dplyr)

df |>
      group_by(grp = cumsum(c(1, diff(lubridate::ymd(date))) < 0) + 1) |>
      rowwise() |> 
      mutate(NewColumn = c_across(city1:city3)[grp]) |> 
      ungroup() |> select(-grp)
```

```
  date       city1 city2  city3  NewColumn
  <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    
1 2022-01-25 Paris London Berlin Paris    
2 2022-01-28 Paris London Berlin Paris    
3 2022-02-04 Paris London Berlin Paris    
4 2022-01-26 Paris London Berlin London   
5 2022-02-08 Paris London Berlin London   
6 2022-02-02 Paris London Berlin Berlin   
7 2022-02-04 Paris London Berlin Berlin   
8 2022-02-06 Paris London Berlin Berlin
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can try this

```
j <- 2
lag_d <- c(0 , df$date)
for(i in 1:(length(lag_d)-1)){
    if(lag_d[i+1] > lag_d[i]) df$NewColumn[i] <- df[i,j]
    else {
        j <- j + 1
        df$NewColumn[i] <- df[i,j]
    }
}
```

- Output

```
        date city1  city2  city3 NewColumn
1 2022-01-25 Paris London Berlin     Paris
2 2022-01-28 Paris London Berlin     Paris
3 2022-02-04 Paris London Berlin     Paris
4 2022-01-26 Paris London Berlin    London
5 2022-02-08 Paris London Berlin    London
6 2022-02-02 Paris London Berlin    Berlin
7 2022-02-04 Paris London Berlin    Berlin
8 2022-02-06 Paris London Berlin    Berlin
```